# Flutter, AppBar Color change

Tags: flutter, background-color, colorbar, appbar

[image]

Is there a way that the AppBars color can be changed through a gradient and opacity as an example?  From something lighter to something darker to see the icons above the phone clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you want to change the appbar color with one of these methods :

**1) change AppBar color only** 
*witch will affect the background of appbar only*

```
     appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
  ),
```

**1) change primary App color swatch :** 
*witch will change all the colors of buttons , etc to a certain color including appbar*

```
MaterialApp(
    primaryColor: Colors.red,

)
```

**2) Switch to dark mode :** 
witch will invert the colors of all app to dark mode

```
MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  theme: ThemeData.dark(),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0.0,
```